# Matlab - randomly generated seeds only spawning one of the 3 desired features

Tags: matlab, if-statement, random-seed

I am trying to model distributions of randomly sized craters in a given landscape. I have 3 diffrent crater sizes. Big ones that spawn infrequently and only during the first half of the model. Medium ones that spawn at a 'normal rate' only during the second half of the model. And small ones that spawn frequently during the whole model.

My issue is that only small ones are spawning. I think it's linked to how I use 'rand' to decide what should spawn. I basically have the following structure:

```
%medium craters
icrater=0;
for k=nstep/2:nstep
        Time_in_Myr=k*dt/1e6;
        med_c=rand
        if med_c>0.98
         icrater=icrater+1;
         x_crater(icrater)=dx*(rand*nx);
         y_crater(icrater)=dy*(rand*ny);
         t_crater(icrater)=k;
     end
 end

%big craters
bigcrater=0;
for k=1:nstep/2
        Time_in_Myr=k*dt/1e6;
        big_c=rand
        if big_c>0.991
         bigcrater=bigcrater+1;
         x_crater(bigcrater)=dx*(rand*nx);
         y_crater(bigcrater)=dy*(rand*ny);
         t_crater(bigcrater)=k;
     end
 end

 %small craters
smallcrater=0;
for k=1:nstep
        Time_in_Myr=k*dt/1e6;
        small_c=rand
        if small_c>0.97
         smallcrater=smallcrater+1;
         x_crater(smallcrater)=dx*(rand*nx);
         y_crater(smallcrater)=dy*(rand*ny);
         t_crater(smallcrater)=k;
     end
 end
```

So what I think it's doing is only spawning small craters because they have the highest spawn rate.

I tried adding the 'med_c=rand' (and equivalent) bits to allow for the code to check the if statement wiht the same random number.

I was expecting to check if each 'if' statement was true, and if one or more of them were, to spawn those craters. So I would end up with a handful of large ones, ten or so medium ones, and a lot of small ones. But I only got small ones.

Comment: my guess is that `buncha code that defines crater position` may be important. Your code can not be reproduced as it is, so your question is not answerable. Or, instead you are asking us to chose some arbitrary numerical vaues for something that is aesthetic in nature, so again, not really an answerable question.

Comment: ah, my bad. I assumed that part was not useful because it's working as intended. I'll add it asap

Comment: You realize you are not using the radious, right? Once the `if` condition happens, you generate a new value for the radious with `rand`. `small_c` is never used, nor the others.

Comment: `small_c` is only there to trigger the `if` function. But it only triggers it for the `small_c` for some reason. the `med_c` and `big_c` are never used, and I don't understand why

Comment: Re-read my comment. Your code to create craters is the same for all cases, you never use anything "big" or "small". I am saying that all your codes for the 3 cases do the same. In any case, this is trivial for you to test. Make medium and small never happen and only big, and see what happens.

Comment: The small craters are overwriting the larger ones.  And as Ander says, you wouldn’t be able to tell the difference anyway.

Comment: okay. But i still don't understand where they are overwriting them

Comment: I think I have sorted it out. I reordered my functions (small, med., big) and it's giving me more sensible results now